# What's the meaning of "I have a soul"?

Tags: idioms, phrase-meaning, humor

From the TV series *How I Met Your Mother*. In episode 9 of season 1, titled:  [*Mary the Paralegal*](http://www.subzin.com/quotes/S459418978/How+I+Met+Your+Mother/Mary+the+Paralegal/Look%2C+I...+Tell+Mary+thanks%2C+but+no+thanks.+I+have+a+soul.), the following expression ***I have a soul*** is used.

What does it mean when someone says: *I have a soul*?

> 00:06:50 Look at how hot she is. Robin would be so jealous.
>
> 00:06:54 I'm not trying to make Robin jealous, Barney.
>
> 00:06:57 Look, I... Tell Mary thanks, but no thanks. I have a soul.
>
> 00:07:01 OLDER TED; And then your Uncle Marshall and I
>
> 00:07:03 had one of our famous

Comment: The implication is that interacting with some "evil" person has been suggested, and the speaker does not want to do that as that "evil" person might, vampire-like, suck out his soul.  Of course, I use "evil" in quotes since the person (whoever that is) is likely just a relatively normal person but with a nasty personality.  It's a sort of metaphor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The soul is sometimes regarded as being the seat of morality, humanity and conscience. Inhuman beings like demons, or extremely evil people, are sometimes described as "soulless".

What the quote means here is that the character isn't going to do what is asked because "I am a human being with morals and a conscience".